# Vimeo API - Accessing information about a hidden video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, vimeo

I am building a feature that enables users to add videos to a site, the user puts in the URL and the site handles the rest. Currently I am supporting Vimeo and YouTube, YouTube was easy however Vimeo is a little more tricky. Essentially I want to ensure the video is embedded without issues, so the URL is validated and then the appropriate API is called to pull information on the video, such as embeddable, or in YouTube's case private.

For Vimeo I am using the oEmbed API implementation which works fine for Public videos without any restrictions.

The problem areas are:

- Videos set as "Hidden from Vimeo" with restricted embed settings return a thumbnail image as desired but nothing in the response indicates the embed restriction so I can not act on it or inform the user.
- Videos that are set as private (link only) do not return a thumbnail, although the rest of the information is returned (embed code etc)

In order to remedy this I have tried using Vimeos Authenticated API which returns significantly more data all around however the above problems are only solved if the videos are mine, based on the access token. If the video does not belong to me the API simply returns Video not found - which is less information than the oEmbed API provides.

The only workaround I can think of would be to request access to the users Vimeo account, via the API, to grab this information, is anybody aware of a simpler solution?

**Note:** I can understand the reasoning behind this but a simple JSON response indicating the video is set to private, or is not embeddable by the calling domain would be very helpful in these cases. Obviously videos that pass validation should display properly.